# Why sails-orientdb tries to create a new database every time i start my app?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-orientdb

I am using sails-orientdb as an Waterline Adapter but there is a problem whenever I restart my application it tries to create a new database which was already created as I am using it for the first time so I don't know the structure and functions and flow of sails-orientdb is it possible to avoid this call?

Comment: Please give more details.

Comment: Ok I am using sails-orientdb as an adapter in waterline I wanted to get and post data in my orientdb database but when i start my server which is node.js application server and its configured with a connection connections: {
    myLocalOrient: {
      adapter: 'orient',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 2424,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
   database:'test'
    }

Comment: whenever there is a database:test in orientdb already it will throw an error but when there is not a database it will work fine

Comment: post your adapter config,

Answer (score 1):

In [sails-orientdb](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb) there is one property

> **migrate** : This setting controls whether/how Sails will attempt
>   to automatically rebuild the tables/collections/sets/etc. in your
>   schema.

Set these `migrate` to `safe`.

> In a production environment (NODE_ENV==="production") Sails always
>   uses migrate:"safe" to protect inadvertent deletion of your data.
>   However during development, you have a few other options for
>   convenience:

1. safe - never auto-migrate my database(s). I will do it myself (by
   hand)
2. alter - auto-migrate, but attempt to keep my existing data
   (experimental)
3. drop - wipe/drop ALL my data and rebuild models every time I lift
   Sails

> When your sails app lifts, waterline validates all of the data in your
>   database. This flag tells waterline what to do with data when the data
>   is corrupt. You can set this flag to safe which will ignore the
>   corrupt data and continue to lift

[See these documentation of Model Settings migrate property](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html)